# Do Red Bull Air Race aircraft make use of nitrous oxide injection?

Tags: piston-engine, air-race

Microsoft Flight Simulator X contains Red Bull Air Race missions where the player flies an Extra 300S through a race course and makes use of Nitrous Oxide injection for the engine.  While I have heard of NO injection for automobile engines, I have never encountered an aviation engine which made use of this.  Can anybody verify if RBAR teams make use of this?

Comment: Isn't that just for making smoke, not improving horsepower?

Answer (score -3):

This is from the 2014 season

http://airrace.redbull.com/en_US/article/lycoming-engines-power-behind-air-race

> In previous years, the race teams were allowed to modify their
>   aircraft, but since 2014, the engines and propellers have been
>   standardised for all teams. The Lycoming Thunderbolt AEIO-540-EXP
>   engine and the Hartzell 3-bladed 7690 structural composite propeller
>   have both undergone rigorous testing and have performed to
>   specification.

Here's a link to a smaller engine using nitrous to get 300 HP out of a 100 HP engine for record setting purposes

https://books.google.com/books?id=DhLSUHx136QC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=lycoming+io-540+nitrous&source=bl&ots=UwecpWRA8S&sig=RgiMHhHnQuHJYph0TASw0Y6bB2o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieiZTGqf7aAhVxUd8KHc5uBLoQ6AEIhAEwDA#v=onepage&q=lycoming%20io-540%20nitrous&f=false

and even more HP here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohannon_B-1

Comment: I don't know that I'd want to be doing that to an engine that costs tens of thousands of dollars and has to last for several races over the course of a week/weekend, however long an event is.  Example:  http://www.airpowerinc.com/productcart/pc/TLEngineDetail.asp?catID=33&prodID=9462

Comment: Could be more like this, I don't see the AEIO-540-EXP listed http://www.airpowerinc.com/productcart/pc/TLEngineDetail.asp?catID=33&prodID=9741 No turbo on this one.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the answer in this post? Do they or do they not use NOx injection in the engines? They may be standardized engines but they could also be standardized NOx (I didn't read the links but answers should stand on their own).

Comment: No they do not. Inferred from the Airpower site and the Red Bull site, neither of which mentions NO as an option to order for IO-540 engine.  Read the links, I am not copying and pasting pages of copyrighted material that has been posted since 2014.